# How to Distinct one column from all the column that i choose in Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

How to Distinct one column from all the column that i choose in Sqlite?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 20):

If you're only selecting one column, it's easy:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM table
```

If you mean you're selecting multiple columns, but only one want one of them to be distinct you can do:

```
SELECT col1 , col2 , col3 FROM table GROUP BY col1
```

Obviously you need to be careful about whether this means you're going to miss some data from col2 and col3 that you need. Sometimes it's better to select more and filter client-side instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DISTINCT](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#select-core) keyword in your query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table
```

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello